# Openshift environment BUILD_NUMBER variable

Tags: openshift

I'm new to Openshift and need to get BUILD_NUMBER from builds and pass it to application pod, is there any ways to pass such environment variable during building and application.

For example, in Jenkins we can get $BUILD_NUMBER variable, how can i implement such solution in Openshift?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you expecting the build number to be and how do you intend using it?

For an S2I build, the build will have certain environment variables set, and this will also be set in the final image. For example:

```
OPENSHIFT_BUILD_NAME=poc-hub-shared-storage-1-hub-img-5
OPENSHIFT_BUILD_NAMESPACE=hubtest7
OPENSHIFT_BUILD_SOURCE=https://github.com/jupyter-on-openshift/jupyterhub-quickstart.git
OPENSHIFT_BUILD_COMMIT=6530d6f6744f063d4c474e82901571b9b7e4a9eb
```

So you are given information on the project, the name of the build pod, the Git repository and the commit ref for the code used in the build.

That number at the end of the `OPENSHIFT_BUILD_NAME` will increment for each subsequent build, but can't say whether that is sufficient for your purposes without knowing what you need it for.